# Groovy returning JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I have the following Groovy script (not a Grails app) that is returning a JSON-like, but it is not strictly valid JSON.

```
 String baseURL = 'https://test.com'
 File userFile = new File("./user.json")
 def client = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
 client.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
 client.request(GET, JSON) { req ->
     requestContentType = JSON
     headers.Accept = 'application/json'
     response.success = { resp, json ->
        userFile.append json.toString()
        println JsonOutput.toJson(json.toString())
     }
 }
```

I am trying to create a JSON output file. I have tried using JsonOutput.prettyPrint and I looked at JsonBuilder, but that looks like I would have to build the JSON structure manually when Groovy should support the output.  This is what I am getting back.

```
{AssetNumber=AssetNumber1, DeviceFriendlyName=FriendlyName1, PhoneNumber=17035551231, SerialNumber=SerialNumber1, Udid=Udid1, UserEmailAddress=user1@email.com, UserId=userId1, UserName=userName1}
```

As I said, this is JSON-like, but not strictly valid.  I was expecting something like:

```
{"AssetNumber": "AssetNumber1", "DeviceFriendlyName": "FriendlyName1"....}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could You please provide the JSON content You get for testing?

Comment: The web service I am calling is returning the valid JSON when I test it via a REST Client.  @Opal, I am not sure I understand your question.  I am providing the JSON.  FYI, I am using Groovy v2.3.6

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it was only a part of what You get. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly fine (groovy v 2.3.6):

```
import groovy.json.*

def pretty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson([1:2]))

assert pretty == """{
    "1": 2
}"""
```

In this closure:

```
response.success = { resp, json ->
   userFile.append json.toString()
   println JsonOutput.toJson(json.toString())
}
```

You're getting an instance of `Map` under `json` variable.  You do not need to turn it into a string.  Instead use:

```
   userFile.append JsonOutput.toJson(json)
   println JsonOutput.toJson(json)
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine.  My use case involves getting JSON back from a web service.  I receive valid JSON when I call the web service from a REST Client (which I show above), but inside my script, it is being converted somehow.

Comment: That is the problem.  `JsonOutput.toJson(json)` fixes the problem (without `.toString()`)

Comment: Forgot to remove it :/ Thanks @cfrick.

Comment: That was it.  Apparently, I tried all variations EXCEPT that one! :-)  Thanks much!